# Cons of using Oauth2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials if I own all Services (no third party)

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am interested in developing a corporate app consisting of several ASP.NET Core services (chat service, file upload, REST apis etc) which will all be accessed through a mobile and desktop app.

To grant acces to these services I would like to implement an authentication service as well using IdentityServer4 (Oauth server implementation)

Most Oauth flows seem interested in granting a web service access to data from yet another web service (get user data from google for instance). To this end the user is redirected to a login endpoint of the resource server (google) where they will verify their credentials, and then return to the original service.

In my scenario however, I am creating a mobile/desktop native app and do not wish to use the browser (required in most oauth flows). Additionally because the authentication server and the services relying on the authentication service are my own there is no third party involved.

Is this the proper use case for the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow? I pass the credentials directly to the auth server, and use the resulting token to access the other services. This seems easy to implement and doesnt rely on a browser, but am I losing security somehow?

Is one of the other flows more secure in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

let look at all the component involve during a login

user -> person using the application

client -> mvc app/spa app

token provider -> sts = identiy server/facebook/google

service-> protected services

the whole concept of oauth is that a user want to give access to a client. it doesn't matter who own or do not own the client. the reason there is a redirect to sts is to make sure  users are not giving their user name and password to a client but instead giving the client a token that contain what the client should be able to do and not do.

using the ropc is the is like a saying a random application this is my user name and password go login into my facebook/identity get a token or what ever you need so you can access  whatever resource you need or do whatever you want.

the situation where this is very bad is if a user give their password to their facebook account to a client so the client can use it to access resource

the reason you want to use identity server is because you want to protect many services/resources in the backend. so when the mobile client/destop request access to resource in the backend. your backend service will be sure that the user using the client is authenticated because the identity server they trust provide the client a token they trust.

when you use ropc, the user give their password to the client the client will use that password to authenticate with the sts then the sts will provide the client a token they will use to authenticate with your backend service.

in your case the main reason why this is bad is that you are polluting the internet by training your users to give their password and username to clients which is preping them for a fishing attack.

the benefit of using the browser is that the users are giving client a token instead of a password. In your case it is technically secure because your backend service can trust the frontend service so it is equivalent to creating an application that collect user name and password. but usually, you want to delegate authenitication to the sts/identityserver instead of having the application handle it.

Comment: I disagree with the fact that i would be polluting the internet. After all the user must enter their password somewhere. And instead of forwarding the auth request to a third party login like google, i would forward the user to another of my own endpoints. So why not skip the forwarding anyway?
Normal Oauth :user->some service ->third party auth ->back to service

My flow : user->my service -> my auth -> back to my service

Comment: oauth does not require you to use a third party auth. when you use identiyserver you are basically creating your own auth server instead of using facebook or google auth server.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main recommendations for desktop / mobile apps:

- Use Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) - and use an external login screen
- Login via the System Browser - so that the app never sees the password

**CORPORATE v PERSONAL ASSETS**

For personal assets ROPC is not considered good, since the user should be socialised against giving their password to apps.

For corporate assets, if there is nothing else the password can be used for, ROPC is sometimes judged acceptable as a bridging solution.

**USABILITY PROBLEMS - ROPC**

With ROPC the only login option you have is passwords, and you will typically log in via a web view / private browser session where features such as password autofill may not work well. This can be a big problem, especially if the user needs to frequently type passwords on small mobile keyboards.

**LOGIN BRANDING**

Sometimes stakeholders care a lot about these aspects:

- They may not like the Authorization Server's login screen or lack of ability to customise it
- For desktop they are likely to find use of the system browser unnatural
- For mobile the system browser feels more integrated

**FUTURE**

Looks like [OAuth 2.1](https://fusionauth.io/blog/2020/04/15/whats-new-in-oauth-2-1) will drop support for ROPC.

**NATIVE APPS CODE SAMPLES**

My [blog](https://authguidance.com/) has some detailed posts on using the recommended flows for desktop / mobile apps. It also has some [demo apps](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/) you can run from your local PC to further evaluate the above aspects.

**SUMMARY**

My preference is to use recommended OAuth flows, so that security is future facing. These flows generally provide solutions where it is easy to login. But there can be trade offs between security, usability, branding and stakeholder opinions.